# Create http or https server for Node.js on Heroku

Tags: node.js, http, heroku, https

I can’t find out if I’m supposed to create an HTTP or HTTPS server for node.js hosted on Heroku. Apparently, paid Heroku apps now handle SSL and receives over HTTPS by default. When the app receives an HTTPS request, the Heroku load balancers convert the request to HTTP and then send the request to your app.

So it seems that Heroku handles HTTPS/SSL for you, and all we have to do is set up an HTTP app.

If the request is sent from the client as HTTP, the following code should be added to ensure encryption on data sent.

```
/* Redirect http to https */
app.get('*', function(req,res,next) {
  if(req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] != 'https' && process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production')
    res.redirect('https://'+req.hostname+req.url)
  else
    next() /* Continue to other routes if we're not redirecting */
});
```

Am I incorrect that that we should use an http app over https because heroku handles encryption?

Answer (score 1):

Heroku provides an SSL certificate and configures it for you so users can go to the `https` version of your site.

What the code in your answer does is forward the user from http to https, essentially forcing all users to use the https version of your site, this is a good thing.

So what the code does is:

1) Check if the user landed on a page with the http protocol

2) If true, redirect the user to the https version of the same address

3) User continues to browse the site in https

So while Heroku handles the ssl for you, you still need to make sure all users use SSL by redirecting http users.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! So I'm learning towards yes, that my node.js app on heroku should be using an http server and not https? Am I correct or is there something i'm missing?

Comment: I think your server would be protocol independent, but you would use https references for all your urls, etc.   There is no harm in using https over http, so you might as well utilize the secure way.